# Updating state through API response not working in react

Tags: reactjs, e-commerce, react-state-management, commerce

im newbie to react.  i  developing a portfoliio project guided by youtube video. when i try  update state in cart icon which is present in the navbar, the page becomes blank

[github link](https://github.com/Gopi9655/ECOMMERCE-APP.git)

```
function App() {
  const [products,setproducts] = useState([]);
  const [cart,setcart] = useState([])
  
  const fetchproducts = async ()=>{
    const {data} = await commerce.products.list();
    setproducts(data)
  }
  const fetchcart = async () => {
    setcart(await commerce.cart.retrieve())
  }
  const handleaddtocart = async(productId,quantity) => {
    const item = await commerce.cart.add(productId,quantity)
     setcart(item.cart)
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchproducts();
    fetchcart();
  
  },[])
  return ( 
    <div className="App">
     <Products  products={products} Onaddtocart = {handleaddtocart}/>
     <Navbar totalitem={cart.total_items} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here is my navbar.js which imports total_value as a prop and   tends to set a value for badge icon

```
export const Navbar  = ({totalitem}) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <>
    <AppBar position='fixed' className={classes.appBar} color="inherit">
      <Toolbar>
        <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" className={classes.title}>
          <img src={logo} alt="zencart" height="25px" className={classes.image}></img>
          ZenMart
        </Typography>
        <div className='classes.grow'></div>
        <div className='classes.button'></div>
        <IconButton aria-label="show cart item" color="inherit">
          <Badge badgeContent={totalitem} color="secondary">
           <ShoppingCart />
          </Badge>
        </IconButton>
        
      </Toolbar >
    </AppBar>
    </>
  )
}
```

i need to display the  state change in cart icon badge whenever i click on the add to cart button

[image: here is my page]

Comment: for you, It's best time to start learning `redux` and `context`

Comment: You say that when you update the state the page goes blank. Is "handleaddtocart" the function that performs this update? If so, did you verify that "item.cart" does indeed have the valid data you need?

Comment: it do have a valid data, and i tried setting the cart by simply setcart(cart). it worked. Im familiar with usecontext. but im following a  utube tutorial. Thanks for ur respponse brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside App component instead of `setcart(item.cart)` correct it to `setcart(item)`

```
const handleaddtocart = async(productId,quantity) => {
    const item = await commerce.cart.add(productId,quantity)
     setcart(item)
  }
```

Comment: thanks a lot brother , i thought my was not using useContext to pass to state to navbar component

Comment: Try to use optional chaining, and instead of props drilling use Context Api

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be that when you pass `totalitem` as a prop to the `Navbar` component it's undefined.
To solve this you can verify first that cart is not undefined and then access to the property of `total_items`, for example by adding a optional chaining `(?.)` operator:

```
totalitem={cart?.total_items}
```

Comment: actually the backend works fine, but not the ui rendering.  i just edited my setcart to setcart(item). boom it works.. thanks for your response dude....